# Is an AA tree stable over insertion order?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Does the structure (order) of an [AA tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree) depend on the order in which its elements are inserted?

And does it matter for the answer of the above question whether the tree contains only unique elements or also duplicate elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider set `{1, 2}`.

If you insert 1, and then insert 2 you will get

```
1
 \
  2
```

If you insert 2, and then insert 1 you will get

```
  2
 /
1
```

So structure of AA-tree depends on order in which its elements are inserted.